# android remove line by finger touch on screen

Tags: java, android

I have a custom view, which function is like canvas.I can draw straight line on the canvas.I draw the line by path.What I want do is to remove random line by touch the line.Anybody can help me ?It is like when we long click our mobile screen, all app shocked and I can select one to remove it.
And another question is the dialog show int this custom view ,I need click four times and the dialog then can dismiss.Anybody know why?Sorry my english is poor,Any question let me know if u can not understand my question.Thanks.

```
package com.icst.symmetry.View;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import com.icst.symmetry.Bean.Axis;
import com.icst.symmetry.Bean.Image;
import com.icst.symmetry.Bean.Line;
import com.icst.symmetry.R;
import com.icst.symmetry.Tools.Util;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by hugo on 16/8/31.
 */
public class PaintView extends View {
    private static final String TAG = PaintView.class.getSimpleName();


    private Paint machinePaint;
    private Paint userPaint;
    private Line mLine;
    private Axis mAxis;
    private Path mPath;

    private ArrayList<Line> machineLines;
    private ArrayList<Line> saveLines;
    private ArrayList<Line> deleteLines;
    private boolean isEraseModel;
    AlertDialog mDialog;

    public PaintView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        saveLines = new ArrayList<>();
        deleteLines = new ArrayList<>();
        machineLines = new ArrayList<>();
        machinePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        userPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mLine = new Line();
        mAxis = new Axis();
        mPath = new Path();
        machinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        machinePaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        machinePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        userPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        userPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        userPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(machineLines.size()!=0){
            for(Line line :machineLines)
                canvas.drawPath(line.getPath(), machinePaint);
        }
        for (Line p : saveLines) {
            canvas.drawPath(p.getPath(), userPaint);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, userPaint);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        if (!isEraseModel) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            for (Line line : saveLines){
                if(Util.isTouched(line,x,y)){
                    showDialog(line);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        return true;
    }

    private void showDialog(Line line) {
        final Line mLine=line;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                saveLines.remove(mLine);
                deleteLines.add(mLine);
                invalidate();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setTitle("是否确认删除这条线？");
        mDialog = builder.create();
        mDialog.show();
    }

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mAxis.setxStart(x);
        mAxis.setyStart(y);
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        mPath.rewind();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mPath.lineTo(mAxis.getxStart(), mAxis.getyStart());
    }

    private void touch_up(float x, float y) {
        mAxis.setxEnd(x);
        mAxis.setyEnd(y);
        mLine.setAxis(mAxis);
        mLine.setPath(mPath);
        saveLines.add(mLine);
        mPath = new Path();
        mAxis = new Axis();
        mLine = new Line();
    }


    public void onClickEraser() {
        isEraseModel = true;
    }

    public void onClickDraw() {
        isEraseModel = false;
    }

    public void drawMachineLine(float[] data,Image image){
        machineLines.clear();
        float left=data[0];
        float top=data[1];
        float scaleX=data[2];
        float scaleY=data[3];
        for(int i=0;i<image.getMachineAxis().size();i++){
            Axis axis=image.getMachineAxis().get(i);
            axis.setxStart(axis.getxStart());
            Line line =new Line();
            line.setAxis(axis);
            Path path=new Path();
            path.moveTo(axis.getxEnd()*scaleX+left,axis.getyEnd()*scaleY+top);
            path.lineTo(axis.getxStart()*scaleX+left,axis.getyStart()*scaleY+top);
            line.setPath(path);
            machineLines.add(line);
        }
        invalidate();

    }
    public void undo() {
        if (saveLines != null && saveLines.size() > 0) {
            Line line = saveLines.get(saveLines.size() - 1);
            deleteLines.add(line);
            saveLines.remove(saveLines.size() - 1);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void redo() {
        if (deleteLines != null && deleteLines.size() > 0) {
            Line line = deleteLines.get(deleteLines.size() - 1);
            saveLines.add(line);
            deleteLines.remove(deleteLines.size() - 1);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you cannot delete a line drawn by path, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261428/android-remove-lines-from-path/37520479#37520479

Comment: Yeah, Your are right,Thank u.So have u have any good idea that can draw straight line with two point(coordinate) and with finger slide(first touch decide start point and draw line dynamic flow finger slide?Because I work for this a long time and I can only do this with path.

Comment: i think the answer from @Manikandan K will lead you to the right solution. when `ACTION_DOWN` set your startpoint, when `ACTION_UP` set your endpoint - then just draw a path between...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. When you touch screen and remove your finger events call :

ACTION_DOWN - when you first touch

ACTION_MOVE - when you are moving your finger on screen

ACTION_UP - when you remove your finger from screen

Good luck!

Comment: Thank u, I know all  u said。